# Extract image within a tube using opencv or others

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm new to image processing and I'm trying to extract the area within a test tube.

The tube will be placed in front of a camera and then the image is captured. The image obtained will be as shown below. However, there will be slight movements of the tube so its not exactly at the same position each time. The Idea is to recognize the tube position and extract an image corresponding to the inside of the test tube (holding some reaction). Can somebody please guide me how to achieve this using OpenCV or any other image processing library. Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you forget to add/link the image?
In endoscopy you have a similar setup: http://www.shergillurology.com/images/Bladder-Cancer-Cystoscopy.jpg where the endoscope might slide over the camera lens slightly. My former colleagues worked on topics handling the motion (for distortion correction in their cases).

Comment: Afair he described his method in `Image Processing for Endoscopy: Algorithms and Real-Time Implementations`

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't post the picture in my post. Here is a link to it: http://postimg.org/image/hx695zdnz/ We have to process the static image after it is captured by the camera (not video).